# zoom всего блока с перетаскиванием

Tags: jquery

Представим блок DIV, размером 1000x500 pix, внутри него другой DIV, размером 2000x1000 с примененным zoom 50%. Причем внутри не картинка, а страница.

обычные кнопки зума прибить не проблема, которые просто меняют параметр zoom у дива, но охота что бы можно было содержимое 'брать мышкой' и таскать в разные стороны

может ли кто подсказать решение, куда копать, или статейку с кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#warp {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#draggable {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#draggable img {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<div id="warp">
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: draggable - оно! спс. пример лучше чем в документации ))